# Odd behaviour in bash (and possibly other shells?)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I do:

```
/bin/bash -c 'cat /proc/$$/cmdline'
```

The output I get is:

```
cat/proc/25050/cmdline
```

Whereas the output I expected was:

```
/bin/bash -c 'cat /proc/$$/cmdline'
```

---

On the other hand when I do:

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo $$; cat /proc/$$/cmdline'
```

I get the expected output, which is:

```
28259
/bin/bash-cecho $$; cat /proc/$$/cmdline
```

---

It seems like $$ is cat's pid rather than bash/sh's pid.
Why is this?
Does the shell do some kind of parsing and `execve()` style replace? If so, how does it know cat's PID before it even does the replace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to understand this behaviour, one has to figure how `bash` executes commands passed to it on the command line. The key point is that if the command is simple enough, *there's no `fork`* (or `clone` or anything like that).

```
$ strace -f -e clone,execve /bin/bash -c 'cat /proc/$$/cmdline'
execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cat /proc/$$/cmdline"], [/* 80 vars */]) = 0
execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "/proc/2942/cmdline"], [/* 80 vars */]) = 0
cat/proc/2942/cmdline+++ exited with 0 +++
$
```

OTOH if the command is more complicated, `bash` forks:

```
$ strace -f -e clone,execve /bin/bash -c 'echo $$; cat /proc/$$/cmdline'
execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $$; cat /proc/$$/cmdline"], [/* 80 vars */]) = 0
2933
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7ff64e6779d0) = 2934
Process 2934 attached
[pid  2934] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "/proc/2933/cmdline"], [/* 80 vars */]) = 0
/bin/bash-cecho $$; cat /proc/$$/cmdline[pid  2934] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=2934, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
$
```

> It seems like $$ is cat's pid rather than bash/sh's pid.

It's actually both. `bash` `execve`s `cat` directly, so one becomes the other.

To understand what exactly is needed for the no-fork behaviour, we need to look at the source code. There's this comment:

```
      /*
       * IF
       *   we were invoked as `bash -c' (startup_state == 2) AND
       *   parse_and_execute has not been called recursively AND
       *   we're not running a trap AND
       *   we have parsed the full command (string == '\0') AND
       *   we're not going to run the exit trap AND
       *   we have a simple command without redirections AND
       *   the command is not being timed AND
       *   the command's return status is not being inverted
       * THEN
       *   tell the execution code that we don't need to fork
       */
```

[Source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/evalstring.c#n343)

Comment: I saw this output when I straced it as well. Where ever it determines that the command is not complex and after tokenization it determines that it does not need to fire any subprocesses (as a result of `;` or `||` or `&&` or `|`) then it simply `execve`s the command pass to it. Otherwise it `clone`s and then `execve`s in the child/clone. What I don't quite get is why.

Comment: @ffledgling There is a comment in the source `IF
we were invoked as \`bash -c' (startup_state == 2) AND
parse_and_execute has not been called recursively AND
we're not running a trap AND
we have parsed the full command (string == '\0') AND
we're not going to run the exit trap AND
we have a simple command without redirections AND
the command is not being timed AND
the command's return status is not being inverted
THEN
tell the execution code that we don't need to fork`

Comment: Would you mind adding this to the answer and linking to the relevant line in the official source?